# Preventing a Certain Text to be Deleted or Change in a RichTextBox

Tags: c#, richtextbox

i have RichTextBox which has a certain default text to load everytime the Form Load .

this text for example:

```
// Do not Exclude this line below
```

i can add text in newline and delete if necessary but must not this line .

like if i delete "e" in word "below" it must comeback to word "below" . same adding space or char .

i started out this code in Keydown Event:

```
Regex donotexclude = new Regex(@"//\s+\s+\s+\s+\s+\s+Do\s+not\s+exclude\s+line\s+below");
            MatchCollection donotexcluDE = donotexclude.Matches(rtb_JS.Text);

            // if (Keys.Space && 

            foreach (Match DONOTEXCLUDE in donotexcluDE)
            {

                if (DONOTEXCLUDE.Success)
                {
                    var donot = DONOTEXCLUDE.Groups[0].Value.ToString();

                    //if (!donot.Length =>
                    //{

                    //}
                }
                else
                {

                }
            }
```

but I dunno what code should I add or if Im doing a wrong thing in the 1st place .

Now my question was "How can I protect a certain text in a RichTextBox from deleting or changing" .

Thanks and More Power!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Don't reinvent the wheel*. Make use of [SelectionProtected](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.richtextbox.selectionprotected%28v=vs.91%29.aspx) property

```
richTextBox.Rtf = ...;
richTextBox.SelectAll(); or richTextBox.Select(start, length)//Select that line
richTextBox.SelectionProtected = true;
richTextBox.SelectionLength = 0;
```

Comment: Rtf is just to setting the text, nevermind if you have already set `Text`

Comment: what should i put for ... in richTextBox.Rtf = ... ?

Comment: You can safely ignore that line if you already have text in RichTextBox

Comment: how can i get that line? sorry for this Q , can i make it something like richtextbox.Select(donot) instead? (something like that)?

Comment: What is that line? What is that "text"? Use `Find` method. Check the link I provided