# Preventing a text to be deleted in a Wpf RichTextBox

Tags: c#, wpf, vb.net

Copy and paste following code into **MainWindow.xaml** file.

```
<Window x:Class="MainWindow"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Grid>
    <RichTextBox>
        <FlowDocument>
            <Paragraph>
                <Run Text="Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book."/>
            </Paragraph>
        </FlowDocument>
    </RichTextBox>
</Grid>
</Window>
```

Run this code and see that you are able to delete that text.

I want you are not able to delete that text.

There is a solution for **WinForm** as you can see in the following link because WinForm RichTextBox **has selection protected** property.

[Preventing a Certain Text to be Deleted or Change in a RichTextBox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19565380/preventing-a-certain-text-to-be-deleted-or-change-in-a-richtextbox)

WPF RichTextBox ***has no selection protected*** property. So how can I solve this issue for WPF?

Comment: `<RichTextBox IsReadOnly="True">`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.

```
<RichTextBox IsReadOnly="True">
```

Or if you want no selection at all.

```
<RichTextBox IsEnabled="false">
```

Answer (score 0):

This question is quite a few months old, but if you are still interested, I created a solution that works to protect text in a WPF RichTextBox, which I'll post if you like.

Edit: Ok I'll just post it anyway, why not :)

So, what this does is allows you to dynamically set ranges that are uneditable, based on a property of the **TextRange**.  The only hack here is having to choose an obscure property that you can be sure is not otherwise going to be found in your **FlowDocument**.
In this case I chose the **DependencyProperty**:  **FontStretches.UltraCondensed**.  But you could use any valid one for a TextBlock.

So, in the **PreviewKeyDown** event of the **RichTextBox**, just add the following code:

```
    // Disable editing of protected text (=UltraCondensed FontStretch)
            if (!(e.Key == Key.Left | e.Key == Key.Right | e.Key == Key.Up | e.Key == Key.Down | e.Key == Key.LeftShift))
            {
                var trange = new TextRange(richTextBox.Selection.Start, richTextBox.Selection.End);
                bool isProtected = false;
                switch (trange.Text.Length)
                {
                    case 0:
                        {
                            // Zero length selection
                            if (e.Key == Key.Back)
                                trange = new TextRange(trange.Start.GetNextInsertionPosition(LogicalDirection.Backward).GetInsertionPosition(LogicalDirection.Forward), trange.Start);
                            else if (e.Key == Key.Delete)
                                trange = new TextRange(trange.End.GetInsertionPosition(LogicalDirection.Forward), trange.End.GetNextInsertionPosition(LogicalDirection.Forward));
                            isProtected = trange.GetPropertyValue(FontStretchProperty) == FontStretches.UltraCondensed;
                            break;
                        }

                    default:
                        {
               //RichTextBox selection has length
isProtected = trange.GetPropertyValue(FontStretchProperty) == DependencyProperty.UnsetValue || trange.GetPropertyValue(FontStretchProperty) == FontStretches.UltraCondensed;
                            break;
                        }
                }

                if (isProtected)
                {
                    e.Handled = true; return;
                }
            }
```

The reason **Key.Left**, **Key.Right**, etc. are excluded is because you still want to be able to navigate through the protected text, and the reason for discriminating between Selection length 0 or non-zero is because if you have length to your selection (multiple **Runs**) and the **Runs** have different properties, then **GetProperty** will return "UnsetValue".

Then to unprotect the text, simply set the "UltraCondensed" (or other property) to "FontWeights.Normal", which is the default.